# Change variable declaration using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to make variable modification using Rolsyn.
Assume we have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string p = "ss";
        int k = 1;
    }
}
```

and after modification this should looks that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string p = "ss";
        int k = System.Math.Abs(1);
    }
}
```

I want to for this purpose use SyntaxWalker, but I can't figure out how exact I should ovveride VisitVariableDeclarator.

**EDIT**

I have initializer in

```
node.Declaration.Variables[0].Initializer
```

and I want to switch this to

```
var expressionSyntax =  Syntax.ParseStatement("System.Math.Abs(" + node.Declaration.Variables[0].Initializer.Value + ")");
```

but I don't know how. I cannot simply pass these to ReplaceNode (wrong types).

Comment: Wrap your expressionSyntax in an EqualsValueSyntax before the call to root.RepleaceNode(initializer, equalsValue);